# Exit code 139 when using Kivy Atlas

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to use the default Atlas with the following code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.atlas import Atlas

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        atlas = Atlas('defaulttheme.atlas')      

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

I get the message

```
[INFO] [Logger] Record log in /Users/Prueba/.kivy/logs/kivy_16-09-16_3.txt
[INFO] [Kivy] v1.9.1
[INFO] [Python] v3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.1.1 (x86_64)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:52:12) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 4.2 (clang-425.0.28)]
[INFO] [Factory] 179 symbols loaded
[INFO] [Image] Providers: img_tex, img_imageio, img_dds, img_gif, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
 **Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)**
```

Note that I moved *`defaulttheme.atlas`* and *`defaulttheme-0.png`* to the folder where the script I'm running is located.

Thanks!

Comment: Is that all what you get? Normally kivy outputs quite some debug information. How do you call the program? If I try your code I get `[CRITICAL          ] [Application ] No window is created. Terminating application run.` (because the build function does not return a widget).

Comment: I updated the full message.

Comment: And the code you showed is all there is? There is no kv file or anything?

Comment: No: I'm just testing the Atlas but it doesn't work.

Comment: What happens if you return a widget from the build function?

Comment: https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.atlas.html take a look at this and try the example and see what happens